# No audio in WebRTC and Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, webrtc, voip, rtp

I have a strange issue with Asterisk (in this case 13.2 version) and WebRTC.

So, I have latest Asterisk 13.2, latest Crome (with Firefox - same problem) and sip.js (also tried with sipml5) and local network - no nat or firewall.

The problem: if call is answered  immediately - everything works fine. But if there are some delay in answer (say, 10 seconds) - no audio in both directions.

In RTP debug I saw that if there is some delay - destination ip address is incorrect. After removing ice servers from client config - both addresses is correct, but still no audio.

Below is debug for call with audio:
rtp http://pastebin.com/EzfByCG5
sip http://pastebin.com/1Y08yF5s

and no audio call (answered after 10 seconds delay):
rtp http://pastebin.com/TNnFkz6M
sip http://pastebin.com/zG7pjcZD

Also in FreeSwitch everything works fine, no matter when call is answered.

Comment: webrtc is experemental protocol and require full understanding and advanced debuggin technics. Use freeswitch if it work fro you.

Comment: sure it works. But I love Asterisk and just want get it to work)
anyway I'll post here link to my blog post if I've find any solution

Comment: Asterisk with IP based telephony (webRTC, SIP softphones) has been hit or miss for me. Each account had to be hand-crafted to match the client. Do yourself a favor, stick with Freeswitch for that.

Comment: You're right. Asterisk has some complexity in config sip accounts. But on other hand Asterisk can do many cool things - lke dynamically dialplan (even read all configuration from DB), REST api, AGI and AMI. All this is good for developers. PS: my experience with FreeSwitch is too small, maybe it can do this too :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Asterisk 12 you need to have pjproject libraries installed, otherwise you most likely won't have audio in your WebRTC calls and no warning whatsoever!

Answer (score 0):

First question:  have you ensured all firewall configs permit RTP streams from the chosen STUN / ICE server unconditionally?

My own experience is that audio issues with WebRTC are almost always related to STUN / ICE & Firewall.

Did you follow a tutorial for your set up?  If so, which one?

Comment: All WebRTC clients are inside local network, so ICE isn't needed here.    

But the bad way - ICE is the problem here. I've made a lot of tests and found that if call initiator is Web RTC client and there is some delay in answer (10-25 seconds) - audio is completely absent. Also in this case in RTP debug can be seen than "sent RTP packet" doesn't have "via ICE" mark. But when call initiator is any SIP client (X-Lite, Ekiga, etc) - WebRTC works perfectly.  

And the answer (as I think) is in rtcp-mux - wich can't do Asterisk but Sofia (SIP library for FreeSwitch) can.

Comment: I've try several tutorials (like this http://sipjs.com/guides/server-configuration/asterisk/ and this https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/WebRTC+tutorial+using+SIPML5), and also try many experiments with sip options.

Comment: Can you post your configs so that we can take a look for something strange?

Comment: Sure. sip.conf > http://pastebin.com/eg9tr1A6  rtp.conf > http://pastebin.com/pGQB8WLh extensions.conf > http://pastebin.com/1CiXhSmv http.conf > http://pastebin.com/KFa3gLny

Answer (score -1):

Check the log...

Peer audio RTP is at port 192.168.88.187:50026
sip_route_dump: route/path hop: sip:889@df7jal23ls0d.invalid;transport=ws
[Feb 13 06:15:59] ERROR[1055][C-00000031]: netsock2.c:303 ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("df7jal23ls0d.invalid", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known
[Feb 13 06:15:59] WARNING[1055][C-00000031]: chan_sip.c:16158 __set_address_from_contact: Invalid host name in Contact: (can't resolve in DNS) : 'df7jal23ls0d.invalid'

I would use Freeswitch, no doubt :-)